# multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered hangs in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Following script hangs when running with Python 2.6.7.  It prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` as expected in Python 2.7.  Could it be a bug in Python 2.6?  Are there any workaround?

```
def p1(x):
    return x + 1


class Tasks(object):

    @property
    def mapper(self):
        from multiprocessing import Pool
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        return pool.imap_unordered

    def run(self):
        xs = range(10)
        return self.mapper(p1, xs)


ts = Tasks()
print(list(ts.run()))
```

In my program, I could workaround the hang by rewriting `Tasks.run` to:

```
    def run(self):
        xs = range(10)
        mapper = mapper
        return mapper(p1, xs)
```

But I couldn't reproduce this with the above script.

Also note that the use of `@property` is essential here.  Assigning `mapper` in `__init__` like the following solves the problem:

```
def __init__(self):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    self.mapper = pool.imap_unordered
```

Comment: hi, i haven't tried this solution, but you can give it a try: http://www.rueckstiess.net/research/snippets/show/ca1d7d90

Comment: I am not sending instance of the class, so I think the link is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a bug in python2.6

The `Pool` object that you're using needs to stay referenced somewhere, otherwise python will hang when trying to use *imap** methods (and possibly others)

Here is a fix for your example. Note that the pool object is kept inside the Tasks object, this may break your existing code.

```
class Tasks(object):
    _pool = None

    @property
    def mapper(self):
        from multiprocessing import Pool
        if self._pool is None:
            self._pool = Pool(processes=2)
        return self._pool.imap_unordered

    def run(self):
        xs = range(10)
        return self.mapper(p1, xs)
```

Comment: It's still a bug in Python 3.6. I just ran into this issue using a Pool instance in a generator. `yield from Pool().imap_unordered(...)` hangs indefinitely, but `pool = Pool(); yield from pool.imap_unordered(...)` works fine.